# Browser doesn't add max-age=0 to some request on browser refresh

Tags: browser, http-headers, httpresponse, browser-cache, squid

I am using Firefox and I am requesting several URLs from server. When reload page by F5 or Cntrl+R, browser re-sends the request to server to re-validate the cached response with server by setting `max-age = 0` in request. This is the desired way the browser should handle the refresh.

But for some URLs, its not resending URLs, instead it serves from its own cache. I want those requests to get revalidated by the origin.

```
**Response Header for this :**

Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Cache-Control   public, s-maxage=0, max-age=21600
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  167
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Wed, 23 Jul 2014 06:51:35 GMT
Expires Wed, 23 Jul 2014 12:51:36 GMT
Proxy-Connection    close
Server  lighttpd/1.4.32
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Via 1.0 roswell:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE21)
X-Cache MISS from roswell
X-Cache-Lookup  MISS from roswell:3128


**Request Header**
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    some-host
Origin  origin
Referer referer
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
```

What could be the reason browser not sending this request again? Please help.

Comment: Did you try this behaviour with more than one browser?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour has something to do with headers, but not those sent from the browser. Browsers aggressively cache any content, except those that have an expired max-age and the setting "must-revalidate" marked in the Cache-Control header **by the server**. What you are seeing is normal browser behaviour for content marked with max-age=21600 from the server.

But now, on with your question:

> I want those requests to get revalidated by the origin.

You have two options to reload the current page, if you are using keyboard hotkeys (as per https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly section "Navigation"); you can just reload (and make use of all cacheable items from cache) or reload overriding cache.

The hotkeys are F5 / CTRL+R for reload using cacheable items, and CTRL+F5 / CTRL+SHIFT+R for reload overriding any cache.